# NumericUpDowns included in iteration over TextBoxBase controls

Tags: vb.net, winforms, types

I have a WinForm with NumericUpDowns (NUDs), normal TextBoxes and MaskedTextBoxes.
The text boxes should be cleared, which I tried this code for:

```vb
For Each txtBox As TextBoxBase In Controls.OfType(Of TextBoxBase)
    txtBox.Clear()
Next
```

This clears the textboxes, but also clears the NUD's text, which it shouldn't.
Looking up the parents of `NumericUpDown` using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Click</kbd>, it didn't even inherit from `TextBoxBase`, as far as I could see.

Still, they got cleared, so I wanted to add a condition to check that `txtBox` wasn't a NUD before clearing it. I tried checking:

```vb
If txtBox.GetType() <> GetType(NumericUpDown) Then
    txtBox.Clear()
End If
```

and also the following conditions:

```vb
txtBox.GetType() IsNot GetType(NumericUpDown)
```

```vb
TypeOf txtBox IsNot NumericUpDown
```

Also all of these with `UpDownBase` instead of NUD. Nothing equaled `False`.

**But** while debugging, I checked the type in the immediate window using

```vb
Debug.Print(txtBox.GetType().ToString())
```

This got `System.Windows.Forms.UpDownBase+UpDownEdit`. There is no type called `UpDownEdit` and I also don't know what exactly I should make of the `+` in there.

What condition **did** work then was to just compare type name strings:

```vb
txtBox.GetType().ToString().Contains(GetType(UpDownBase).ToString())
```

But this is hardly a nice way to go about this, so:
What is the "right" way to check if the object in `txtBox` is really a NUD, given the challenges mentioned?

The method this problem comes up in is the following recursive sub:

```vb
Public Sub ClearInputControls(elements As ControlCollection)
    ' Recurse into containers.
    For Each pnl As Panel In elements.OfType(Of Panel)
        ClearInputControls(pnl.Controls)
    Next
    For Each cntr As ContainerControl elements.OfType(Of ContainerControl)
        ClearInputControls(cntr.Controls)
    Next
    ' Reset controls.
    For Each txtBox As TextBoxBase In elements.OfType(Of TextBoxBase)
        txtBox.Clear()
    Next
    For Each count As NumericUpDown In elements.OfType(Of NumericUpDown)
        count.Value = count.Minimum
    Next
    For Each cbox As ListControl In elements.OfType(Of ListControl)
        cbox.SelectedIndex = -1
    Next
End Sub
```

If the value in the NUDs is changed from their default, they don't get cleared.
But this seems to be that any *change* in the value prompts the NUD to show the number again, so the second for each loop only updates the NUD if the value is different from the minimum (which is default).
As it comes *after* the clearing loop, values are shown again because of an update through change.

Comment: No, that does not/should not happen. The loop as is doesn't yield the NUDs. It does yield `TextBox`, `RichTextBox`, `MaskedTextBox` controls if any in the `Controls` collection. Where do you call that loop? In a `Form`? Do you have any recursive call that traverses the `NUD.Controls` collection and yields its second internal control? The [UpDownEdit](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/UpDownBase.cs,1249) which is by the way internal ( `+` ) `TextBox` control defined in the `UpDownBase` class. Please clarify and double check your code.

Comment: Agreed. Your `for` loop did not pick up NumericUpDowns in a simple test case.

Comment: @dr.null I found the issue and you're right, it's not in the loop I provided above. The loop gets called in a function that recurses into all controls of type `Panel` and `ContainerControl` to also clear all textboxes in `Panel`s, `SplitContainer`s and the like. The issue is, NUDs are `OfType ContainerControl` and what they contain is `OfType TextBoxBase`. When looking at the definition using Ctrl+Click for NUDs, it only took me to UDB, not further down, but looking at the NUD class documentation now, it does inherit from CC. Should I edit the question and answer myself or just delete it?

Comment: I think posting an answer that tells what you have found from digging up the source code will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue now – and the comments were right: It's not in the one loop I originally provided in the question.

The loop gets called in a sub that recurses into all controls `OfType ContainerControl` to also clear all text boxes in SplitContainers and the like:

```vb
Public Sub ClearInputControls(elements As ControlCollection)
    ' Recurse into containers.
    For Each cntr As ContainerControl elements.OfType(Of ContainerControl)
        ClearInputControls(cntr.Controls)
    Next
    ' Reset controls.
    For Each txtBox As TextBoxBase In elements.OfType(Of TextBoxBase)
        txtBox.Clear()
    Next
End Sub
```

The issue is, NumericUpDowns (NUDs) are `OfType ContainerControl` (CC) and what they contain is `OfType TextBoxBase`.
So the for each loop "opens" a NUD as a CC. This CC "holds" a TextBoxBase that is then cleared by the for loop.

When looking at the definition using Ctrl+Click for NUDs, it only took me to UpDownBase, not further down, but looking at the NUD class documentation now, it *does* indeed inherit from CC.

So the solution is to change the for each loop to only iterate over SplitContainers:

```vb
For Each cntr As SplitContainers elements.OfType(Of SplitContainers)
    ClearInputControls(cntr.Controls)
Next
```

The for loop over TextBoxBases can stay as-is.

Alternatively, to keep using CCs, a check for `OfType NumericUpDown` before recursion could be done:

```vb
For Each cntr As ContainerControl elements.OfType(Of ContainerControl)
    If TypeOf cntr IsNot NumericUpDown Then
        ClearInputControls(cntr.Controls)
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to do separate loops to traverse the different types of control in a given collection. You have in one procedure loops to do the recursive part and others to deal with the target controls. Split-solve the problem.

First, create a [recursive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/recursive-procedures) method that gets all the child controls of a given parent.

<sup>**Note:** Options [Strict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement), [Explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement), and [Infer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-infer-statement) are `On`.</sup>

```vb
Private Function GetChildren(parent As Control) As IEnumerable(Of Control)
    Dim ctrls = parent.Controls.Cast(Of Control)
    Return ctrls.SelectMany(Function(c) GetChildren(c)).Concat(ctrls)
End Function
```

Second, a caller method that traverses the child controls, handle the target types, and skip the rest.

```vb
Private Sub ClearInputControls(parent As Control)
    For Each element In GetChildren(parent)
        If TypeOf element Is NumericUpDown Then
            Dim nud = DirectCast(element, NumericUpDown)
            nud.Value = nud.Minimum
        ElseIf TypeOf element Is ListControl Then
            DirectCast(element, ListControl).SelectedIndex = -1
        ElseIf TypeOf element Is DateTimePicker Then
            DirectCast(element, DateTimePicker).Value = Now
        ElseIf TypeOf element Is TextBoxBase Then
            If Not element.GetType().IsNested Then element.Text = ""
            ' Or...
            ' If TypeOf element.Parent IsNot NumericUpDown Then element.Text = ""                
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Better yet, you can extend the type `Control` and have the recursive routine as [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/extension-methods). In `vb.net`, you need to have the extension methods in a [Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/module-statement) and decorate them with the `<Extension>` attribute.

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module ControlExtensions
    <Extension>
    Public Function GetChildren(parent As Control) As IEnumerable(Of Control)
        Dim ctrls = parent.Controls.Cast(Of Control)
        Return ctrls.SelectMany(Function(c) GetChildren(c)).Concat(ctrls)
    End Function
End Module
```

Now, all the objects of type `Control` in your project have this method.

```vb
Private Sub ClearInputControls(parent As Control)
    For Each element In parent.GetChildren()
        ' ... etc.
    Next
End Sub
```

Moreover, you can have a generic extension method that gets a specific type of controls if you need one.

```vb
Module ControlExtensions
    <Extension>
    Public Function GetChildren(parent As Control) As IEnumerable(Of Control)
        Dim ctrls = parent.Controls.Cast(Of Control)
        Return ctrls.SelectMany(Function(c) GetChildren(c)).Concat(ctrls)
    End Function

    <Extension>
    Public Function GetChildren(Of T)(parent As Control) As IEnumerable(Of T)
        Dim ctrls = parent.Controls.Cast(Of Control)
        Return ctrls.SelectMany(Function(ctrl) GetChildren(Of T)(ctrl)).Concat(ctrls.OfType(Of T))
    End Function
End Module
```

Call it like this.

```vb
For Each element In parent.GetChildren(Of GroupBox)
    ' ...
Next
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm still pretty much a "beginner", so can you explain, why using an extension is "better" than using a simple function? For me, the only difference seems to be `GetChildren(parent)` vs. `parent.GetChildren()`. Also, using your idea I could forego the extra recursion function altogether again and just use one loop with If/ElseIf, recursing as I did before. So what is the advantage of doing it your way with an extra function? Also also, isn't it less efficient to loop over everything than to loop over specifics? Or does VB do a selection loop internally each time?

Comment: What happened to the referred links? For each question in your comment a doc link contains the answer and more. 1) Use the ex. methods or not, it's up to your coding taste and understanding. 2) Avoid the so-called _spaghetti_ code. Separate your routines for better readability, usability and maintenance. Master the [OOP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/object-oriented-programming) for that. 3) A method that works in any scenario is better than another that should be modified per scenario. Try to change your UI layout and run your code to get it.

Comment: @Rsge 4) As for looping over everything vs. specifics. You need to do the math: looping over a collection 4+ times does not make it any better. Think, why would you loop over again and again to do the same thing? Again, please read the referred links carefully. See also, [Option Infer Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-infer-statement).

Comment: Thank you for your explanations. I have `Option Explicit` and `Strict` `On`, but `Infer` `Off`, so everything has to be declared with `As`. I prefer it that way as it makes the type more visible to me. | 4) As I understood it at first, I iterated over *selections of* the main collection each time, while with one loop I'd iterate over *everything* and ignore what doesn't fit. Still, using just one loop is more readable and also has the advantage, that it's easier to implement an exception list this way. So I'll change that.